# Detecting position tapped with UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: objective-c

Hi so I was wondering if there was any way possible to get the position that was touched using UITapGestureRecognizer to recognize taps on the background.

```
-(void)handleTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized)
{
    if ( bomb == nil)
    {
        bomb = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bomb.png"]];
        bomb.center = CGPointMake(10, 1);
        bomb.frame = CGRectMake(113,123,67,67);
        [self.view addSubview:bomb];
        //[self performSelector:@selector(Update) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
        NSLog(@"Spawned bomb");
        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.01 target:self selector:@selector(dropBomb) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }
}
}
```

Comment: First, `UITapGestureRecognizer` only fires `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded`. And you can get the location of the tap with `CGPoint pt = [sender locationInView:myView];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure there is! Use `locationInView:` to get the CGPoint location of the touch on your image view.

```
CGPoint touchLocation = [sender locationInView:sender.view];
```

Or, if you are allowing multiple touches, you can use the following to specify which touch you are interested in.

```
CGPoint otherTouchLocation = [sender locationOfTouch:0 inView:sender.view];
```

Comment: Does that return CGPoint x and y coords or just int?

Comment: @AdamS. It returns a CGPoint object which has two properties, x and y. Both of these properties are declared as CGFloats. (float)